# How to reference a dynamic type using dictionaries?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dictionary, dynamic

So to start with, here is my code as follows:

```
public static class ApplicationCacheDictionary
{
    private static Dictionary<string, Type> CacheDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Type>
    {
        {"X1", typeof (class1)},
        {"X2", typeof (class2)},
    };

    public static Type GetMatchingType(string y, string x)
    {
        var key = x + y;
        if (!CacheDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
            return null;
        else
            return CacheDictionary[key];
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then in another class I have the following code:

```
dynamic appCache = ApplicationCacheDictionary.GetMatchingType("X", "1");
dynamic result = ApplicationCache.Get<List<appCache>>("X1");
```

Here is the definition of the Get:

```
public static T Get<T>(string key) where T : class
{
    try
    {
        return (T) Cache.Value[key];
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem I am running into is with the line

```
dynamic result = ApplicationCache.Get<List<appCache>>("X1");
```

I receive the following error message: "is a variable but used like a type".  I initially tried solving this problem with the following code:

```
dynamic result = ApplicationCache.Get<List<dynamic>>("X1");
```

This compiled but I received a null value where there should be one (hardcoding in the actual class in the place of dynamic works, but I'm trying to get away from that.)  Any suggestions on what else I can try to get this working?

Comment: Sounds like [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: The usage of generics seems unreasonable in this case because you don't know the type at compile time. Is there any reason why you want to use generics?

Comment: Also you should provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
dynamic result = ApplicationCache.Get<List<appCache>>("X1");
```

On this line, you're telling the ApplicationCache's Get method to use the type `List<appCache>` as T. This won't work, as you're trying to pass in a variable instead of a type as a generic type. This also doesn't seem like what you would want to accomplish with this code.

Instead, invoke the function like this:

```
dynamic result = ApplicationCache.Get<dynamic>("X1");
```

This will cast the type in the dictionary to dynamic and return it to your dynamic variable.

That said, this doesn't seem like a good use of generics. The cache you are dealing with will always return either `Type`, or `null`. I'm not sure what your intentions are here. Are you just trying to get a cached Type? do you want an instantiation of that Type?

Comment: Thanks for responding, using:  

    dynamic result = ApplicationCache.Get<dynamic>("X1");  

worked!  I'm not sure why that cache always returns type or null, that is code that was there before I got here.  I added a breakpoint for when the error is there to see what happens and it looks like there are null values passed to it causing the error so I may have to look into figuring out how to improve that.